# Android Studio: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED]

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I work on Android Studio with `Meizu MX6`. Previously everything was ok. But it seems after updating `Flyme`, I started getting this problem:

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3492W.jpg]

If I choose "Ok" I get next:

> DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR

When I work with another smartphone all right. If I copy apk-file on my phone all right too. It installs and runs. Install software from unknown sources is on.

Comment: I have the same issue, have you found a solution?

Comment: Have you tried to install apk by the adb install? It works correct to me, but adb shell pm install which is used by the android studio fails.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I had the same issue. It happens only on `Flyme` due to `Security` App.
To enable installation:

1. Open Security Application. (it is one of preinstalled `Flyme` apps)
2. Go to Permission
3. Usb app installation.
4. Turn off USB installation monitor.

Have found the solution here: http://bbs.flyme.cn/thread-1106582-1-1.html using Google Translate.

Comment: It helps, my phone is MEIZU MX5.

Comment: The issue isn't about a particular version, but more about Flyme OS permissions policy.

Comment: Works on Pocophone F1 as well

Comment: it's possible do all your instruction with ADB?

Answer (score 39):

I also had the same problem with my ***Xiaomi Redmi note 3***.
here's how i solved it,

1. Go to `settings`>>`Additional Settings`.
2. Go to `developer options`.(if its not there, first goto `about phone`
   and tap on `build number` 7 times...and start again from step 1)
3. Click on `install via USB`.
4. That's all, you are ready to rock :)

Comment: the same for me, and it requires a Mi account to turn this option on

Comment: And also a sim card. Seriously Xiaomi??

Comment: In fact, disabling "MIUI Optimizations" was enough. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48524656/3763032)

Answer (score 10):

I have had the same problem with XIAO MI.

I went to Settings ->  Additional Settings -> Developer options -> Turn On "Install via USB"

Only you **can activate** this switch i**f you have a Xiaomi count**, create and activate your count, then sign on and turn on install via USB.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

The device is temporarily restricted error appears in MIUI 8.5.
To resolve the error you need to make **WIFI off** and **make mobile data** on and then **enable the option “Install via USB”**.
It will work for you.
Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

In my Redmi4 i had the same issue.
The steps followed to overcome:
(1)

1. Settings -> About Phone -> tap 7-8 times the MIUI version(to activate Developer Options)
2. Settings -> Additional settings-> Developer Options -> enable USB
   debugging -> install via USB

DONE

Answer (score 3):

On Redmi Note 4, Go To 
Settings --> System & Device (Additional Settings) --> Developer Options --> Install via USB.

Register using a mobile number(OTP).

Try again, should work.

Answer (score 2):

Redmi Note 7 and pro In developer options Allow USB Debugging, Install Via USB and disable Verify apps over USB

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a rooted phone with some application installed that manages App Access authorisations, like King Root?

I had faced with same problem on one of the devices. There was an app on device with super user access that was blocking the new installation. Had to approve installation in that app first before installing new apks.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs when you select the option "remember my choice" and Decline accidentally.

The only solution I found was to change the name of the package and application, but this is not feasible in many cases.

Another solution ont Rednote 11 is to go toi Settings > Applications > Authorizations > Install > Installation via USB.

Comment: this was my issue also.. it's ridiculous not being able to reset that setting

Answer (score 1):

If you got this after mistakenly "Cancel"-ing when you must have selected `Remember my choice` then some dirty fix would be to:

1. Manually copy the same debug apk from your build output to the same test phone.
2. Manually install the apk. (You have to allow installation from unknown sources of course)
3. Go to "App Manager" and clear preferences.
4. Restart the debug as usual.

NB: This was put up in a hurry after some wasted hours so, I'm yet to verify if  step #3 is necessary for this to work.

NBB: You'd be back to square one if you uninstall the app and try to do a fresh install from the debug so, apparently, the `App Manager` preference reset doesn't cover whichever subsystem it is that governs the setting.
Yes, I know, this should infer that our first #NB is void but things don't always follow intuition so, I'm leaving it till it's verified. :D

Answer (score 1):

For **MIUI**, I've found a way to unblock the app installs if you have acidentaly marked the option to always block it.

## Reset options to "Always block" app install

Open "Configurations" > "Apps" > "Manage Apps" > Permissions > Install via USB.

Disable the switch for your app.