# Android Studio can not install the app

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to create my first android application. For this purposes I use Android Studio 2.2.3. I have created the simple app with the single activity and which does nothing, just empty screen and no more else.

I'm developing on Meizu MX6 and I switched ON the next options:

- Security App -> USB installation monitor
- Settings -> Fingerprint and securiry -> Unknown sources
- Settings -> Accessibility -> Developer Options -> USB debugging

Also have configured udev rules.

When I press the Run button I see this message:

```
Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?
```

And after pressing OK this log appears in the console output:

```
$ adb push /home/***/dev/android/HelloAndroid/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.android.hello.helloandroid
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.android.hello.helloandroid"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.android.hello.helloandroid
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED]


$ adb shell pm uninstall com.android.hello.helloandroid
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
Error while Installing APK
```

Can somebody explain how to fix this?

Comment: Seems like someone had the same kind of trouble : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40534271/android-studio-failure-install-failed-user-restricted and has a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40534271/android-studio-failure-install-failed-user-restricted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio: Failure \[INSTALL\_FAILED\_USER\_RESTRICTED\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40534271/android-studio-failure-install-failed-user-restricted)

Answer (score 0):

Check if current user have root access. And enable developer mode if you didn't do this yet.

Answer (score 0):

Please build once again, after clearing temp folder and remove build directory in project.